# Getting Ubuntu software center on 16.04

Tags: 16.04

My old hard drive had ubuntu 15.10 on it and I upgraded to 16.04 on it and had both Ubuntu software and Ubuntu software center. I got an SSD and put it in my computer, then did a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04. I found out very quickly that a clean install of 16.04 does not give you Ubuntu Software Center. I prefer Ubuntu Software Center over Ubuntu Software. Is there any way I can get Ubuntu software center on my SSD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself. I downloaded it from this site: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/software-center/